# Ссылка в шаблоне Thymeleaf

Tags: java, jsp, thymeleaf

Переношу код с JSP на Thymleaf и уперся в следующую проблему. Необходимо вывести на странице ссылки вида:

```
http:\\localhost\remove\1
http:\\localhost\remove\2
http:\\localhost\remove\3
```

где цифры в конце url соответствуют id сущности book

В JSP это делается так:

```
<a href="<c:url value='/remove/${book.id}'/>">Delete</a>
```

Как тоже самое сделать с помощью Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a th:href="@{/remove/{bookId}(bookId=${book.id})}">Delete</a>
```

или

```
<a th:href="@{'/remove/' + ${book.id}}">Delete</a>
```

Почитать можно [здесь](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls).

Answer (score 1):

В ссылки можно и логику вставить

```
<form method="get" th:action="@{/{id}(id=${user.isAdmin()}?'admin':'user')}">
<input type="submit" value="to Main"/>
```